# create a new variablename in properties file at each run of perlScript

Tags: perl

my variable  inside the properties file is $starttime and the value is current date in YYYYMMDDHH24MI after i run second time a new variable with $stattime_2 with current date value.

my code is

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Time::Piece;
$starttime = localtime->strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M');
$i = 0;
open my  $file, '>', 'order.properties' or die $!;

print $file "Start_time", $i, " = ", $starttime;
close $file;
```

for each run the order.properties file should update like

at first time

```
Start_time_1 = 2018121317:04(the current system Time)
```

at second time

```
Start_time_2 = 2018121317:05.........
```

3rd,4th,5th the variable name should change and current date and time should assign

OUTPUT will be like
at 3rd run

```
Start_time_1 = 2018121317:04
Start_time_2 = 2018121317:05
Start_time_3 = 2018121317:09
```

How may execution of Script equal to the entries of start time in the properties file

Comment: Can you please tell us where exactly you have problems? This seems like a straightforward matter of programming to me.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to give you a complete answer as you'll learn more by working it out for yourself. But I will point out the two things you'll need to fix.

1. You open your file using `>`, which overwrites the file each time you run your program. You need to, instead, use "append" mode, which adds new data to the end of your file. You do that by using `>>` instead of `>`.
2. You also need to work out which number gets appended to `Start_time`. Obviously, your program closes down each time it finishes, so you can't store it as a variable. I would suggest that the easiest approach is probably to count the lines that are currently in the file before writing your new lines.

Two more pieces of advice. The [Perl FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html) is a great source of Perl programming advice and you should **always** have `use strict` and `use warnings` in your Perl programs.

Comment: You could use File::ReadBackwards to get the last line of `order.properties` and extract `$i` from it.